# How to stop bots from racking up your firebase bill on a web app?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am learning web development and I am using Firebase as my backend. I am planning on preventing bots from brute force attacks which will rack up my firestore bill by:

1. Only allowing logged in users to write to the database with security rules.
2. Using Firestore & security rules to only allow a certain amount of writes per second per user. If the user goes over this amount they will be banned for a certain time period.

**Will these 2 security measures stop most bot attacks?**

Also I was looking at the pricing for hosting and I saw it costs $0.15 per 1 GB of data transferred.

My entire web application is only about 5 mb of data, but that means if my web application is loaded 1,000 times then it would cost me 5 mb * 1,000 = 5 GB * $0.15 = $0.75 which I can handle. But let's say someone got a bot to re-load the page 1,000,000 times then it would cost me 5 mb * 1,000,000 = 5,000 GB * $0.15 = $750. Obviously $750 is a lot of money and I can't handle that.

**How do I prevent bots from re-loading my page multiple times and racking up my hosting bill?** I can't use the listed strategy above because I want users who don't have an account to still be able to view my website.

Comment: Can you please explain why you are loading the 5 MB data everytime? Also checkout [Firestore bundle](https://firebase.blog/posts/2021/04/firestore-supports-data-bundles) if you are serving same data repeatedly.

Comment: Mainly because I didn’t know you can split it up I guess haha? I only have 1 index.js file because I’m using react and it is about 5 MB of data. How do you split it up?

Comment: What is your question about? Firestore or your the website on Firebase hosting? And what you do you mean by split? Are users supposed to access the whole data on Firestore?

Comment: More importantly is there no way to stop them from loading it? Cause Even if I can decrease it then it still doesn’t make that big of a difference if a bot makes 1 M requests.

Comment: My main question is just how do you stop bots from loading your website repeatedly? Because the more times they load it the more times I am charged for Firebase hosting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*First, a few clarifiers*…

1. Cost of FB hosting is $0.15 per GB **after** you have exceeded the free usage of 10GB/month.
2. Your entire application may be 5MB but that is likely not the amount of data transmitted unless you missed a build step. In a React app, resources are loaded only as needed. Responses are then even further compressed by Firebase to save bandwidth.
3. Assets are generally cached and not reloaded on subsequent page views. It’s a bit more nuanced with bots but this helps keep data transfer rates down overall.

*Now to your question…*

Mitigating repeat page visits the way you describe is handled mostly through rate limiting. This limits the number of requests to your site in a given period.

Implementing Google Analytics can also help in detecting bot traffic by reporting unusual bursts of activity.

You could also use a CAPTCHA to reduce bot attempts to log in or submit other form data.

Two-factor auth is another good tool in preventing brute force attacks.

Finally, I would suggest creating budget alerts for your project. This is easy to do and highly customizable. You can even set it for $1 if you wish. It will **not stop** your project automatically, only send you an email. But if handled quickly, it will save you from getting an even bigger bill.

Comment: thanks for the help! But do you have any suggestions for mitigating repeat page visits by rate limiting? I know how you can do this with a logged in user because you can use firestore to count each time a user visits the page, but since the user won't be logged in when visiting the page for the first time how would you track this?

Comment: Rate limiting is handled at the server level. Firebase likely already has this in place by default as any good server would. Though their docs are unclear. If you still fear being a target, you could run some middleware as a Firebase Function express-rate-limit. Rate limiting packages do the work for you. You can also dig into Google Cloud Security docs as all FB Projects are just Google Cloud projects. Cloud Armor has specific solutions for rate limiting.